# Azure Function to CosmosDB

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

Need help on getting a function that would take a json and write the values to a cosmos DB. Everything I have read shows only single parameters.

```
name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        count = 1
        try:
            counter = container_client.read_item(item=name, partition_key=name)
            counter['count'] += 1
            container_client.replace_item(item=counter['id'], body=counter)
            count = counter['count']
        except exceptions.CosmosResourceNotFoundError:
            # Create new item
            container_client.create_item({'id': name, 'count': count})
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}! Current count is {count}.")
```

This code works but would like something **{name:Kyle, job:engineer}** and these get added to table.

Answer (score 0):

I am following this [blog](https://evan-wong.medium.com/create-api-using-azure-function-with-python-and-azure-cosmos-db-afda09338d82) to achieve your requirement.

Try to add the `json` values in the below format and insert them into **cosmos** DB.

```py
if  name:
    newdocs = func.DocumentList()
    #creating the userdetails as json in container of a cosmosdb
    newproduct_dict = {
        "id": str(uuid.uuid4()),
        "name": name
    }
    newdocs.append(func.Document.from_dict(newproduct_dict))
    doc.set(newdocs)
```

[image]

by using this I can able to add the **JSON** values in **Cosmos** DB.

[image]